# How to limit canceller role in OpenZeppelin governance?

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, governance, timelock

In openzeppelin governance contracts, a proposal can be [cancelled](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/governance#TimelockController-cancel-bytes32-) by a wallet that has the canceller role. As the deployer of the DAO, I want to ensure the security of my DAO, hence I want to be able to cancel **some** proposals, but not all of them. If I have the canceller role, I can cancel all proposals which is not something that I want and is completely centralized. Is there a way to limit the role so that I cannot cancel some proposals? (An example provided below).

**Example**
Say that someone created a proposal which is not feasible to implement. I want to be able to cancel that proposal. On the other hand, someone created a proposal to change the reward given to the governance members. I shouldn't have the power to cancel it. How can I achieve that? Below is how I grant the CANCELLER_ROLE. I'm using time lock controller in governance and admin is me:

```
const CANCELLER_ROLE = await contractTimelockController.CANCELLER_ROLE();
  await contractTimelockController.grantRole(
    CANCELLER_ROLE,
    admin.address
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a design question. I would personally allow/deny the cancellation at a `proposal` level, not at a `role`: Only `CANCELLER_ROLE()` can cancel proposals, BUT, only some proposals can be canceled.

The logic to decide if a proposal is eligible for cancellation is not trivial, but this is regardless of where you want to implement this logic. I would suggest you first try to answer this :

- What defines a proposal that I should be able to cancel?
- How can I characterize such a proposal? what characteristics?

Then, once that is identified, Perhaps, when creating a proposal, it could have a boolean like `can_be_cancelled_by_caneller_role=true`.

Comment: I also thought the same "boolean flag" thing but then I realized anyone can create a proposal. Meaning anyone can set this flag to anything they want.

Comment: Maybe I should change who can create the proposals. I don't know :S I'm confused atm. Let me drink my coffee :D

Comment: And btw. From what I see, a proposal can only be cancelled after it is voted and when it is in the queue state which is the only state a proposal is "pending". Only during this "queue" state "isOperationPending" is returning "true" and cancellable. https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/governance#TimelockController-isOperationPending-bytes32-

Comment: True, but in any case, the question is still relevant I guess. I bet is not an easy task to classify the proposals as cancelable or not ...

Comment: You are right, Your solution should work for governance systems that doesn't allow anyone to create proposals but allow an admin (or some form of it) to create proposals on-chain.